# Using HikariCP with Mysql: who should implement the threadpool

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb, jersey, hikaricp

I'm running 2 instances of a Java app using HikariCP with a maximum pool size of 30 each. They connect to a single MariaDB database which also has `thread_handling         = pool-of-threads` set. I have been getting some connection timeouts from Hikari when there is a high number of simulataneious DB reads.

```
2024-03-20 00:09:17.551, qtp1047503754-22 , [DEBUG] Get team query time, 8ms
2024-03-20 00:09:18.432, pool-3-thread-3 , [DEBUG] Get team query time, 5ms
2024-03-20 00:09:52.305, qtp1047503754-29 , [DEBUG] Get team query time, 6ms
2024-03-20 00:09:56.720, qtp1047503754-27 , [DEBUG] Get team query time, 5ms
2024-03-20 00:10:00.232, qtp1047503754-24 , [DEBUG] Get team query time, 4ms
2024-03-20 00:10:01.329, pool-3-thread-4 , [DEBUG] Get team query time, 4ms
2024-03-20 00:10:04.553, qtp1047503754-25 , [DEBUG] Get team query time, 4ms
2024-03-20 00:10:05.787, pool-3-thread-3 , [DEBUG] Get team query time, 6ms
2024-03-20 00:10:06.353, pool-3-thread-4 , [DEBUG] Get team query time, 3ms
2024-03-20 00:10:14.178, qtp1047503754-22 , [DEBUG] Get team query time, 293ms
2024-03-20 00:10:14.184, qtp1047503754-27 , [DEBUG] Get team query time, 953ms
2024-03-20 00:10:14.185, qtp1047503754-29 , [DEBUG] Get team query time, 739ms
2024-03-20 00:10:14.197, qtp1047503754-24 , [DEBUG] Get team query time, 523ms
2024-03-20 00:10:14.201, qtp1047503754-28 , [DEBUG] Get team query time, 92ms
2024-03-20 00:10:15.414, qtp1047503754-25 , [DEBUG] Get team query time, 861ms
2024-03-20 00:10:15.425, qtp1047503754-167 , [DEBUG] Get team query time, 417ms
2024-03-20 00:10:16.177, qtp1047503754-26 , [DEBUG] Get team query time, 1838ms
```

The query time keeps increasing and eventually HikariCP times out at 30s. The query time goes back to normal after the request count goes back to normal. For context: I'm just reading a row from a simple table with a WHERE on the primary key.

Should I just let HikariCP handle the connection pool and set the Mariadb thread handling to thread per connection or do I have to match the sizes of the pools?

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use more than 30 connections simultaneously, and you got only 30 connections in connection pool, you'll have a problem. Just increase that number.
Also on MariaDB server side, `thread_pool_max_threads` .It can be set to hundreds if not thousands, it does not really affect the performance that much.